# Where are Raleigh and Herc in Uprising?

Tags: plot-explanation, pacific-rim-uprising

In *Pacific Rim: Uprising* Mako Mori, Newton Geiszler, and Herman Gottlieb made an appearance, but no signs of the characters of Raleigh Becket and Herc Hansen.

Where are they? Is this explained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where are they? Is this explained?

In terms of the movie...**NO**.

> But Pacific Rim Uprising director Steven DeKnight only referred to Raleigh’s fate as a mystery during my recent phone interview with him.
>
> "What happened to Raleigh Becket, yes indeed," DeKnight said. "In a version of the movie, that was answered. I decided I really wanted to remove that because I thought it painted us into a bit of a corner. So the mystery of what happened to Raleigh Becket is something that I actually want fans to be asking."
>
> He continued, "And it’s my hope - unfortunately, Charlie Hunnam couldn’t do this movie because of a scheduling conflict -- but it’s my hope to bring him back in a future installment, and actually answer that question on-screen."
>
> <sup>[Source](http://uk.ign.com/articles/2018/03/23/pacific-rim-uprising-what-happened-to-raleigh-beckett)</sup>

---

As for Herc...this is not mentioned although I believe he was promoted to Marshall

One theory is that he just retired..but again, the movie is silent on this.

> Uprising, taking place 10 years after the events of Pacific Rim, Herc Hansen would be 55 years old. Obviously not that old in the grand scheme of things, but definitely getting up there in age, so it would make sense that he would consider stepping down from such a dangerous position. So that could be a contributing factor.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.hybridnetworkyt.com/happened-herc-hansen-pacific-rim-uprising/)</sup>

..but there are others.